# Add customized node in OrgChart using orgchart.js

Tags: orgchart

I want to add a custom node in org chart by using orgchart.js getting fromhttps://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart.
A node which is to be create given in the .png file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUpdf.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two choices currently. One is callback "createNode". The other one is option "nodeTemplate". I'm sure you could be inspired by the following exampls on the OrgChart repo homepage(https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart).

1. I wanna customize the structure of node
2. I want to use complex template to customize the internal structure of every node

Comment: For every javascript libraries, I prefer to use ES6 versions if any, because I will use them in my React application. However, for your orgchart library, I find that its ES6 version is not as complete as its jQuery one. For example, I don't find nodeTemplate in the options, although there is createNode option to get the same result. I am still experimenting with your library in my React app. Maybe you can recommend which version is better for React app, esp in terms of completeness in features, although ES6 version is always easier/more straightforward to use.