# OrgChart - Modifying the nodes and adding children - using jquery

Tags: jquery, orgchart

I am asking this question on the reference of this question:[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50095479/how-to-add-children-using-orgchart)

Here's the code from the above link:

```
var datascource = {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'Lao Lao',
      'title': 'general manager',
      'children': [
        { 'id':2,'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'id':3,'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager'},
        { 'id':4,'name': 'Hong Miao', 'title': 'department manager' },
        { 'id':5,'name': 'Chun Miao', 'title': 'department manager' }
      ]
    };

    $('#chart-container').orgchart({
      'visibleLevel': 2,
      'pan': true,
      'data' : datascource,
      'nodeContent': 'title',
      'nodeId':'id',
      'createNode': function($node, data) {
        $node.on('click', function(event) {
          $('#chart-container').orgchart('addChildren', $node,
            {'id' : 7,  'name': 'Hong ', 'title': 'Test manager' }
          );
        });
      }
    });
```

please tell me how do I add more data to the node (#node-2) as shown in the following image
[image]

So that there will be, in the same #node-2, 
1.Hong Miao
2.Department Manager
3.ABC (example text)

**EDIT:** I have already seen the following links, they don't share the code: 
1.[Add customized node in OrgChart using orgchart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806835/add-customized-node-in-orgchart-using-orgchart-js)

2. https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart
 But could not get my answer. 
 please tell me, the code, how to add levels within the node itself as explained above in the image and the immediately following listed text.

Comment: Most likely by changing the `nodeTemplate` https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962530/style-node-of-dabengs-orgchart-library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add customized node in OrgChart using orgchart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806835/add-customized-node-in-orgchart-using-orgchart-js)

Comment: @freedomn-m the marked duplicate neither addresses what I have asked here nor does share the code. see the edited question now.

Comment: No, but it does link to the official orgchart samples, which does have code (open page, view example).  Do you need it copy+pasted here for you?

Comment: Your question is how to add more data to the node.  The answer is, as linked, "callback `createNode`." or property `nodeTemplate:`.   SO is not a free code writing service; you're expect to put at least minimal effort in, not get us to provide a complete solution for you.

Comment: @freedomn-m got you.  can you help me understand this: in javascript code how is `class='content' ` working bcs there's no mentioned css ; link - 
 `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErzxgN`

Comment: In chrome, right click the element to look at and select Inspect.  Find the "styles" panel and look for `.content` - it will show you the source, in this case it's jquery.orgchart.min.css - which has been added as an external css resource in the pen.

Comment: @freedomn-m  in Eclipse ide I couldn't find this `.content` class. Please tell me how can I find and edit this class

Comment: that makes no sense - are you saying you edit the codepen.io in Eclipse?  It works in the codepen.io and I was showing you how to find *how* it works **in the codepen.io** - it doesn't work in your code which was the problem and you need to add jquery.orchart.css

Comment: @freedomn-m no no.. I have set up the complete project in eclipse and have built a few levels but I have a case where a particular field of a particular node need to accommodate more than one String in a numbered format and hence I need  that field to readjust itself according to the data as shown here - `https://codepen.io/amirhasan/pen/ErzxgN?editors=0110` in this link the UI is getting affected. that I need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new property in datasource and implement nodeTemplate:

```
var datascource = {
'id': 1,
'name': 'Lao Lao',
'title': 'general manager',
'office': '',
'children': [
{ 'id':2,'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager','office': ''},
{ 'id':3,'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager','office': ''},
{ 'id':4,'name': 'Hong Miao', 'title': 'department manager','office': 'Data'},
{ 'id':5,'name': 'Chun Miao', 'title': 'department manager''office': ''}
]
};
var nodeTemplate = function(data) {
return `
<div class="title">${data.name}</div>
<div class="content">${data.title}</div>
<div class="content office">${data.office}</div>
`;
};
$('#chart-container').orgchart({
'visibleLevel': 2,
'pan': true,
'data' : datascource,
'nodeContent': 'title',
'nodeTemplate': nodeTemplate,
'nodeId':'id'
});
```

More info:

https://rawgit.com/dabeng/OrgChart/master/demo/custom-template.html